# open activity based on string value or shared preferences value

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to open activity based on string or shared preferences value when press button. I have two activity Home1 and Home2. I need to open Home1 activity when value is 1 and open Home2 activity when value is 2. 
How can i do this ?

Comment: did you have tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

`OnClick` of button check wats the value string or sharedPref `if(string.matches("1")) {open Home1;} else open Home2;}`